# Rails 4/postgresql - Send data to another randomly chosen rows of another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails 4 app and postgresql9.4 as database.

I have a `Deal`, `DealPrize` and `Prize` models.

Prizes have a quantity and a name. For example `prize1` has name `dvd` and quantity  `67`.
`DealPrize`s have a column `deal_id` and `prize_id`

```
class Deal
  has_many :prizes, dependent: :destroy   
  has_many :deal_prizes, dependent: :delete_all
end

class Prize
  belongs_to :deal, :foreign_key => 'deal_id'
  has_many   :deal_prizes,  dependent: :destroy  
end

class DealPrize
  belongs_to :deal,  :foreign_key => 'deal_id'       
  belongs_to :prize, :foreign_key => 'prize_id'
end
```

Database structure:

```
create_table "deal_prizes", id: :bigserial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                    
    t.integer  "deal_id"
    t.integer  "prize_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

create_table "prizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "prize_name",         limit: 255
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "deal_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false    
end

add_index "prizes", ["deal_id"], name: "index_prizes_on_deal_id", using: :btree


create_table "deals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",          limit: 255
    t.string   "description",   limit: 255    
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false   
end
```

I'm gonna take an example to explain what I want and so far fail to achieve:

- **I need to select all the prizes associated with Deal id= 5.** 
  For example I will get as result
  prize id=5  => dvd (whose prize.quantity =67)
  prize id= 9 => Cd  (whose prize.quantity = 32)
- **then send these prizes** (that is to say the 67 DVDs and the 7 CDs) in **randomly** chosen rows inside the DealPrizes rows where Deal_id = 5 AND prize_id=empty (needed so that if it has already been attributed a prize, it should not be again put another prize inside the same row)

Note: I don't want to find them and write on rows that are consecutive: i need random rows.

- **then WRITE into these Dealprizes randomly chosen rows**. so I'll write on 67 randomly chosen rows prize_id = 5 and on 9 randomly chosen rows prize_id = 9

*Note:* the number of rows in DealPrize is superior to 2 millions so need for performance is required.
I would rather use **raw sql** than active record and will try to **not use Rand and random functions directly on the whole table** like this guy advice not to http://www.adamwaselnuk.com/projects/2015-03-28-here-be-taverns.html

> "The problem is these can lead to performance issues on larger tables
>   because when you say "Hey database order the table randomly and then
>   give me the first row" the table says "Okay, I am going to go through
>   every single row and assign it a random number and then limit my
>   selection to one". Asking for one thing results in a computation on
>   every single row in the table!"

I'm totally new to Rails so I could only explain/map the different steps needed on Models/deal.rb

```
# 1. find the first prize where deal_id= seld.id
# and take each of the prizes quantity and id ofr the next steps
def find_prizes_for_this_deal
  Prize.find_by deal_id: self.id  # here I could only find one, don't know how to find many prizes at once and keep both id and quantity
end

# 2. choose Deal prize's table randomly chosen rows (created for the same
# deal attached to prizes) where deal_id=self.id and prize_id = empty    
def DealPrize.random
  # trick found here http://www.adamwaselnuk.com/projects/2015-03-28-here-be-taverns.html, in order not to use the poor-performance rand() methodon the whole table
  offset(rand(count)).first.where(["deal_id = ?", self_id] && prize_id= nil)
end

#3. send the prizes selected in step 1. into the randomly chosen rows of 
# DealPrizes in step 2
def NO IDEA here how to do this at
end
```

How to make this work ?

Comment: Please, update your question with structure of your tables (you may find it in `db/schema.rb`) and post the contents of your models.

Comment: thanks for your comment. added schema so database structure is clearer

Comment: I also need your `Deal`, `Prize` and `DealPrize` models. Thank you.

Comment: Here you go, just added

Comment: It seems `Deal` and `Prize` models are related to each other via many-to-many relation (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/images/has_many_through.png). Is it so? Why do you need `prizes.deal_id` then?

Comment: no a prize belongs to a Deal. Deal and Prizes do not have a a many to many relation. I just posted exactly what I have.

Comment: I do need Deal prize seperate for specific reasons. It's a bit my fault: it is too easy to think wrongfully that what I called deal_prizes is a has many-has many intermediary table but it's not. I should have called it differently: we could call it Opportunities

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89967/discussion-between-alexey-shein-and-mathieu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot that needs to be done for this problem. I can help you out with most and point you in the right direction.

The first part has been answered

```
<pre><code>deal = Deal.find(5)
prizes = deal.prizes
</code></pre>
```

You can loop through prizes

```
    prizes.each do |prz|
      d_id = prz.deal_id
      p_id = prz.id
      quantity_count = prz.quantity
    end
```

To get the quantity of the first prize

```
quantity_count = prizes[0].quantity
```

Or get one prize by id

```
prz = prizes.where(id: 5)
```

I suggest creating two new arrays that will store random numbers to use in your queries. Get the last record id from deal_prizes to be your max number.

```
max = DealPrize.order("id").last.id
```

Based on the quantity count, loop to populate array with random numbers

```
first_prize = []
(1..quantity_count).each do |n|
   first_prize << rand(max)
end
```

You can use that array the find or update records

```
DealPrize.where(id: first_prize).update_all(deal_id: d_id, prize_id: p_id)
```

Or if your going to hardcode it

```
"UPDATE deal_prizes SET deal_id = #{d_id}, prize_id = #{p_id} WHERE id IN ( #{first_prize.join(',')} )"
```

Be mindful of updating records with prize_id not null or zero (however you indicate it). You can run queries till you find exactly 67 records that have prize_id is null.

```
good_rows = DealPrize.where(id: first_prize).where("prize_id IS NULL")
bad_rows = first_prize - good_rows
```

and then replace ids in bad_rows by randomly generating new ids and query again. Continue doing that till you find all good rows then update by adding your new set of good rows with the existing one `perfect_first_prize = good_rows + new_good_rows`

Comment: thanks for the guiding points. I'll try it tonight. I don't understand the end wuth bad rows. i just need to update prize_id attribute in rows where prize is Null. if the riws where prize_id is not null (wha you call bad rows) why do i have to "replace" them with anything? i just let them stay like they are : i din't need to change them at all. no?

Comment: i mean instead of iterating rows one by one, through good and bad rows in deal_prizes table, why not just select good rows that meet the criteria prize_id is null and only change those?

Comment: Sorry it's not working : indeed in your solution you update all the DealPrizes and inject a deal_id BUT I need to SELECt among the DealPrizes ONLY the rows where deal_id=12 (that's an example) and prize_id is Null, then randomly insert into that group of rows into one of them prize_id= 24 (that's an example again of course). You update_all the deal_id but it's not what I need: I need to apply the update(prized_id=XX) ONLY on Dealprizes' rows where deal_id= a certain id.

Comment: The deal with the good and bad rows is that you want to insert n amount of rows. n = quantity. by first selecting random numbers, we don't know if all those numbers have prize_id is null. That is the logic behind replacing them. that's just one consequence of randomly generating numbers yourself instead of the db doing it. Iterate one by one through each id is the long way of doing it. variable first_prize is an array of all the random numbers generated and the query to check for bad ones returns a group of ids back. add the method .pluck(:id) to get an array back of ids. i forgot that part

Comment: from your original question, I didn't understand clearly what to update. Change the update query to DealPrize.where(deal_id: first_prize).update_all(prize_id: p_id)

Comment: Devor brought me the clostest but thanks also to Alexey.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very complex and confuses me a lot. Let's go step by step.

> I need to select all the prizes associated with Deal id= 5.

That's easy.

```
deal = Deal.find(5)
prizes = deal.prizes
```